# How to debug IMCE javascript problem

Tags: 7, javascript, debugging, files

I have a D7 site with CKEditor + IMCE. The main site (www.example.com) IMCE works as expected. My staging site (cloned w/ Backup & Migrate) (staging.example.com) IMCE javascript is not working correctly.

Edit a node. 
Click the image tool in CKEditor
Click "Browse server"
IMCE window opens
imce init function runs and adds the proper classes and such to the DOM
end of story...any click events from there on out have no effect.

Inspecting w/ Firebug or Chrome doesn't show any errors. I've tried to set breakpoints and watch variables but I need some guidance here about how to go about tracking down the root of my problem.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: did you set the `$cookie_domain` in `sites/default/settings.php`?

Comment: yes, I tried that to no effect.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have a similar problem.